# Split Text and number IN VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have `column header` which I want to `split`

**Heading**
XA 2009
WW YY 2010
XXA 2011

I Want output like

**XA,
WW YY,
XXA**

Earlier I was using find function in `excel` which was working fine

**=MID("XA 2009",1,FIND(" ","XA 2009",FIND(" ","XA 2009")+1)-1)**

OUTPUT AS **XA,
WW YY**

Now requirement has change to code in vba

I was trying to use Instr() instead of find as it is not working in VBA

**Mid("XA 2009", 1, InStr(1, "XA 2009", " ", InStr(1, "XA 2009", "2")) - 1)**

Now the output is XA,
WW instead of WW YY.

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong. I am pretty new to vba.

I Want output like

**XA,
WW YY,
XXA**

I am using `excel 2013`

Comment: I've just updated my answer with the complete and tested solution for your edited requirement. Please mark it as the solution for your question.

Answer (score 1):

First, see in the answer for the following SO question, the general approach and prerequisites for using Regex search in VBA:

[How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)

Now, as for your specific requirement, try the following pattern:

```
(\D*)\s+\d*\s+(\D*)\s+\d*\s+(\D*)\s+\d*
```

It will work for your precise example, but if you need the input string to be a bit more general you might need to modify the pattern.

Some explanations:
\D* will match one or more non numerical text characters ("alpha character")
\s+ will match at least one space character
\d* will match one or more numerical digits
the (parenthesis) are for grouping sets of results, so I used them to surround what you wish to extract from the input string.

If for example you know for sure that there's only one white-space character you can use:
[\s]
So the pattern might look like:

```
(\D*)[\s]\d*[\s](\D*)[\s]\d*[\s](\D*)[\s]\d*
```

Also, this is a great tool for online pattern testing:

https://regex101.com/

This is the solution for your edited requirement:

1. In the VBA editor, go to tools=>references, find and select the checkbox next to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5", press ok
2. add this code to "ThisWorkbook" module:

   ```
   Private Sub solution()
       Dim regEx As New RegExp
   Dim strPattern As String
   Dim myInput As Range
   Dim myOutput As Range

   Set myInput = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
   Set myOutput = ActiveSheet.Range("A2")

   strPattern = "(\D*)[\s]\d*[\s](\D*)[\s]\d*[\s](\D*)[\s]\d*"

   strInput = myInput.Value

   With regEx
       .Global = True
       .MultiLine = True
       .IgnoreCase = False
       .Pattern = strPattern
       End With

       If regEx.test(strInput) Then
           ActiveSheet.Range("A2") = regEx.Replace(strInput, "$1, $2, $3")
       End If
   End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You probably had that formula in a specific cell, right? I think the following should do:

```
Range("yourcell").FormulaR1C1 = "=MID("XA 2009",1,FIND(" ","XA 2009",FIND(" ","XA 2009")+1)-1)"
```

Just replace "yourcell" with the cell number you had the formula in. So if you had it in cell A1, for example, it should be `Range("A1")`

Comment: I would like to use vba . Find is not working in vba code